# Any trick to use the ground pin?

Tags: ground, charger, shock

I have bought a new charger for my laptop. The case of my laptop is made of steel and so it sometimes give electric shock as I don't have a ground wire in my house.
And, I currently don't have any mood and time to call an electrician to get me a ground wire. Here is the picture of my laptop's charger plug:

[image: plug]

Is there anything I can do to connect the ground pin like putting something in it may do the work or something else?

Comment: @DonFusili I forgot to mention that the old charger also used to give some electric shock.

Comment: GRound pin or grounded outlets will not help this problem as I answered.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no trick I can recommend, other than calling the electrician.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to get a minor shock from the laptop charger SMPS high frequency primary switching thru the isolation transformer coupling capacitance.  This charger also has Y caps intended to suppress conducted SMPS noise and also to suppress incoming lightning transients picked up by the line as antenna to the common mode pair of power lines.

In practice the ground protects you these potential lightning surges by series CM chokes and shunting Y caps to earth.

The ground pin does not protect you from minor earth leakage currents limited by the coupling capacitance in the isolation switching ferrite transformer.

You should only feel these currents by touching a corner with a sensitive part of the body that is also connected to earth ground, like the household plumbing or metal appliances or wet grass outside or damp floors.

These should not kill you but they can cause a burning sensation on the wrist or knee.

The simple fix is when using the charger to also connect a chassis ground from the laptop using either the USB metal housing or pin 7 on the VGA connector (Gnd) to objects I previously mentioned that flow thru you.  THis way they go around you thru from the metal case to whatever was causing the shock.  This is your local ground or 0V connection for now.

**Let me repeat. Having an earth ground will only protect you from distant lightning surges that have no path for attenuation on your charger ground pin line filter.  It will not prevent the other leakage.  But as I suggested above, it will eliminate the mild leakage..**

This happened to me once sitting outside with an earth grounded extension cord and the slight tingle burn as I described.  I then connected a VGA cable to an earth grounded monitor and that was all I needed to bypass the current. The same could be done with any wire to a ground rod outside or the copper plumbing which goes underground.

I am not responsible for what you do, but I am just sharing my experience.